# Component from local namespace only in design time, like <d:local:UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I get that combining namespaces seems absurd. I want to do something like: <d:local:UserControl ... But how to make custom UserControl visible only in design view? By using :d prefix I can make component exist only in design view, but my custom component is alread from other namespace. How to somehow merge to of them?

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChessBoardAnalizer.Components"
xmlns:dlocal="d:local"
```

This does not work obviously.

I have tried to declare new xaml namespace and to its value add two links. Not possible. I have tried to use other ways to alter visibility of component, but all of them invole using code-behind file, which seems messy to do for such a design flow problem. The obvious solution seems to be:

```
<d:ViewBox>
    <local:UserControl/>
<d:ViewBox/>
```

But this is about clean code.

Comment: Designer data could perhaps set a bool true which is bound to visibility on a control using a Boolean to visibility converter. That bool would be false at run time.

Comment: Having a design data is beneficial, but having a design control is a bit counter-intuitive. What are you trying to do?

Comment: All Wpf controls involve some code though. You could check if the designer is attached and collapse if it isn't. Maybe a visual studio add on would be an idea. Depends what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

not pretty

```
<ContentControl>
     <d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <local:UserControl/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
</ContentControl>
```